# Swift and Python: identical code results in different results

Tags: python, swift, python-2.7

**This question contains the solution to Project Euler Problem 1. Stop reading now if you want to figure it out yourself.**

---

I solved [Project Euler Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) in Python, so I decided to do the same in Swift as well. But: here's the thing, with identical code I get two different results in Python and Swift.

The answer in Swift is 1000 off (too high). In Python the result is `233168` and in Swift it's `234168`.

## Python

```
s = 0

for n in range(0, 1000):
    if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0:
        s += n

print(s)
```

Result:

```
233168
```

[Try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/eee6bqqco2)

## Swift

```
var s = 0

for n in 0...1000 {
    if n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 {
        s += n
    }
}

print(s)
```

Result:

```
234168
```

[Try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/eee6b35c7o)

---

*My question is*: why is that? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the Swift code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Python` range does not include right end, So the last `1000` is exactly the difference, and swift range includes the right end! In Python it is done mainly for arrays to do `range(len(some_collection))`

In Python make it `range(1,1001)` **or** in swift `1...999` and you'll get the same results.

Comment: Or `0 ..< 1000` in Swift (which is pretty common for ranges).

Answer (score 2):

The PE problem #1 asks for numbers *below* 1000 which are divisible
by 3 and 5. The Swift equivalent of `range(start, stop)` is `start ..< stop`, using the `..<` operator which creates a range *omitting* the upper bound:

```
for n in 0 ..< 1000 { ... }
```